# react, Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: reactjs, функции, warning

React, code:

```
    const Home = ({ user, history, profile }) => {
    if (!user.token) history.push("/pages/login");

    const uploadRef = useRef(null);

    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState("About Me");
    const [video, setVideo] = useState(true);

    return (
    <div className="home">
      {!user.token && <Redirect to="/pages/login" />}

      <h3>
        Your personal profile information
        <span className="ml-2 home__title">Preview</span>
      </h3>
      <ProfilePhoto profile={profile} />
      <div className="home__block">
        <div className="home__block__self">
          <span>Full Name</span>
          <Input className="home__block__self__input" placeholder="Full Name" />
        </div>
        <div className="home__block__self mt">
          <span>Location</span>
          <Input className="home__block__self__input" placeholder="NY" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="home__block">
        <span className="home__block__label">Describe Yourself</span>
        <div className="home__block__editor">
          <DefaultEditor
            value={editorState}
            onChange={(e) => setEditorState(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="home__block">
        <span className="home__block__label">
          {video === true ? (
            <span>
              Upload Video Or{" "}
              <span
                className="home__block__label__change"
                onClick={() => setVideo((prevVideo) => !prevVideo)}
              >
                Add Link
              </span>
            </span>
          ) : (
            <span>
              Add Link Or{" "}
              <span
                className="home__block__label__change"
                onClick={() => setVideo((prevVideo) => !prevVideo)}
              >
                Upload Video
              </span>
            </span>
          )}
        </span>
        {video === true ? (
          <div className="mt">
            <div className="home__block__file__fake">
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src={Upload} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className="home__block__file__fake__title">Drag and drop</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className="home__block__file__fake__title__disabled">-or-</p>
              </div>
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <Button.Ripple
                  styyle={{ width: "300px" }}
                  outline
                  color="info"
                  onClick={() => uploadRef.current.click()}
                >
                  Select a file on your computer to upload
                </Button.Ripple>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input type="file" className="home__block__file" ref={uploadRef} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="mt">
            <label>Link</label>
            <Input placeholder="Link" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="home__block">
        <IndicateLessons profile={profile} />
      </div>
      <div className="home__block">
        <PrivateTutoring profile={profile} />
      </div>
      <div className="home__block">
        <Awards profile={profile} />
      </div>
      <div className="home__save">
        <Button color="primary">Save</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const props = connect((state) => ({ user: state.auth.user }), null);

export default props(Home);
```

Вылетает: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within` render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`. Если переписать с помощью классового компонента, то ошибки не будет. Из-за чего это происходит?

Comment: Переместите этот `{!user.token && <Redirect to="/pages/login" />}` код в useEffect

Comment: Поставьте в ответ, я приму. Спасибо большое!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас одна и та же логика написано два раза.

```
if (!user.token) history.push("/pages/login");

{!user.token && <Redirect to="/pages/login" />}
```

Используйте эту логику один раз когда компонент монтируется внутри хука эффекта

```
useEffect(() => {
   if( !user.token ) {
     history.push("/pages/login"); // Желательно роуты отделить 
   }
}, []);
```

И не нарушайте  [**правила хуков**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)